# Are there long pipes that either increase speed of water or at least do not decrease it?

Tags: pipe

I need a long pipe of almost 100 m for filling water into buckets at my home from municipal tap provided outside of my home.

Many people have to share that municipal tap and hence a hose would allow me to get the water I am allotted in less time when my turn comes.

There are two issues involved in it

> 1) The velocity of water either decreases or water flow gets stop
>   because the pipe can't be horizontal and there are some elevations the
>   pipe has to go through.
>
> 2) Should not forcefully pull the water from the municipal tape
>   because of the legal reasons.

Comment: Elementary fluid dynamics will tell you that maximum velocity of fluid in a pipe depends upon the bore and the viscosity.  So, the larger the bore, the better.

Comment: Did you have in mind temporarily connecting a flexible hose to the municipal tap to flow water to your house (100 meters away)? Were you intending to leaving this hose in place when you are not drawing water? Will this hose be above ground?

Comment: Did you have in mind temporarily connecting a flexible hose to the municipal tap to flow water to your house (100 meters away)?

*YES*


Were you intending to leaving this hose in place when you are not drawing water?

*NO*

Will this hose be above ground?

*YES*

Comment: You can get a 1" garden hose, you will only be able to draw water as fast as the supply you are drawing from. If the source is 60psi then  the largest hose in the world will not draw water faster then the 60psi will supply.

Comment: Is the destination for this water uphill from the tap or downhill from the tap?

Answer (score 1):

Water speed has nothing to do with it.  All pipes have a very, very large surface to interact with the water therein (hydrodynamic term: "wetted area"), and will quickly brake any water velocity.

No, water moves because of pressure.  For passive movement, that means height/gravity.  The trade language for height is "head".  The pressure is 1 atmosphere per 10m of height (about 1 psi per 2 feet).   Water does not flow uphill.  If you have a hill to climb, you either need forced pumping..... or for very small climbs, highly competent use of syphons.

Obviously you cannot syphon more than 10m of head, since the pipe would be 100% vacuum inside.  You do need a pump capable of removing air at the top of the syphon. (The mouth will do for less than 800mm, fit a check valve so you don't get spit in the pipe).

Mesopotamia and the Indus Valley had the [finest water engineering](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_empire) in the history of the world, until the [British](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_British_canal_system) gained the [crown](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falkirk_Wheel). And they weren't the only ones. So mastery of hydraulics might be your birthright!

Answer (score 0):

Any time you connect a hose or pipe to a tap, you run the risk of backflow if the pressure in the supply would drop below that in the following piping. The main concern with backflow is contamination of the supply from the following piping. For that reason the municipality may not allow connections with hoses. You might be required to have an air gap between the municipal tap and your hose or pipe.

I could imagine that your procedure might be to draw water into a bucket or other container and pour it into a container of larger volume which has your hose or pipe connected at the bottom. From there it would drain by gravity or be pumped through the hose to your location.
 If there are significant elevation changes on the route of the hose, you would probably need a pump. Presumably for reasons of security the pump would be located at your house.

If you leave the hose in place between uses it will be subject to damage by rats.

**EDIT** But uncoiling 100 meters of hose every time you want to draw water may be too much effort.

**EDIT2** A pump located near the public tap would have the advantage that it *could* pump over an elevation rise  of more than 10 m above the tap because there is no limit on the positive pressure of the output of a pump.  But a pump located at your house would be a suction pump and could not pump over an elevation rise of over 10 m.

What is the elevation profile from the tap to your house?

Comment: The legal issue is that: we may take extra water if we pull using some sort of machines...

Comment: @hanugm You will not be pulling from the tap with the pump instead you will be pulling from a secondary container that you fill from the tap using standard means